# Lengthy epochs when using Keras Datagenerator

Tags: python, image, keras, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement a semantic segmentation task over a kaggle dataset https://www.kaggle.com/franciscoescobar/satellite-images-of-water-bodies.
I have processed the data using Keras datagenerator and it looks like this -

```
seed = 42
BATCH_SIZE = 50
HEIGHT = 256
WIDTH = 256
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,
                 rescale=1./255,
                 validation_split=0.1,
                 height_shift_range=0.1,)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,
                 validation_split=0.1,
                 rescale = 1./255,
                 height_shift_range=0.1,)

train_image_generator =image_datagen.flow_from_directory("data/image/",
                                                    color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                    class_mode=None, seed=seed,subset='training',
                                                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    target_size = (HEIGHT,WIDTH))

train_mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory("data/mask/",
                                                   color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                   class_mode=None, seed=seed ,subset='training' ,
                                                   batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                   target_size = (HEIGHT,WIDTH))

validation_image_generator =image_datagen.flow_from_directory("data/image/",
                                                    color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                    class_mode=None, seed=seed,subset='validation',
                                                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    target_size = (HEIGHT,WIDTH))

validation_mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory("data/mask/",
                                                   color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                   class_mode=None, seed=seed ,subset='validation',
                                                   batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                   target_size = (HEIGHT,WIDTH))

train_generator = zip(train_image_generator, train_mask_generator)
val_generator = zip(validation_image_generator , validation_mask_generator)
```

but after that when I have trained the model using the model.fit method,
code -

```
EPOCHS = 70
callbacks = [WandbCallback() , tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience = 1)]
BATCH_SIZE = 50
history = model.fit(train_generator ,
                    epochs = EPOCHS,
                    validation_data = val_generator,
                    verbose=1,
                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

But the epochs are taking much more time than it usually takes and the epoch run shows something like this

```
Epoch 1/70
   1557/Unknown - 2038s 1s/step - loss: 0.2131 - accuracy: 0.5625
```

Why is it taking too much time?? anybody, please help.
I am also attaching the corresponding notebook I made: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1V7nVgKsOfRM6Qqoq4GTq0g_MNzGwUr1M?usp=sharing)

Comment: Since you use zip on the generator, you should set steps per epoch in fit, as the steps information was lost in between.

Comment: Okay, sir. Will it increase the speed of the training?